# How to configure dovecot to login through ssl connections only

Tags: dovecot

I'm configuring dovecot not to connect via non-ssl ports. To achieve that I have made the following changes in dovecot.conf.

```
protocols = imap pop3
service auth {
  user = root
}

service imap-login {
  process_min_avail = 16
  user = dovecot

  inet_listener imap {
      port=0
  }
}
service pop3-login {
  process_min_avail = 16
  user = dovecot

  inet_listener pop3 {
    port=0
  }
}
```

This works in not letting the user login through non-ssl ports of imap and pop3. The part I do not know is how I need to further configure it for, say, roundcube know that it should use SSL connection only?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dovecot can't be configured to require SSL/TLS connections from the localhost. Manuals is clear:

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/SSL/DovecotConfiguration

> Note that plaintext authentication is always allowed (and SSL not required) for connections from localhost, as they're assumed to be secure anyway. This applies to all connections where the local and the remote IP addresses are equal.

Client can choose between encrypted and unencrypted connection when used port 143, and forced to use encrypted connection when used 993. If you want to force the use of TLS on both ports you have to add the next block into `dovecot.conf`:

```
local 1.2.3.4 {
  ssl = required
}
```

Here 1.2.3.4 is the outer IP-address.